# Does compiler compiles all included header files along with the main program every time we compile that program?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, header

According to Wikipedia this is what the [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) does:

> "The preprocessor replaces the line `#include <stdio.h>` with the text of the file '`stdio.h`', which declares the `printf()` function among other things."

So if this is true, a program which includes more header files would take more time to compile?

Comment: Keep in mind that logic usually does not go into `.h` files. It contains constants, classes and functions definitions, but the code goes into `.c` or `.cpp` files (which are not compiled automatically)

Comment: Does function definition not mean logic?

Comment: @ajay, my bad, I should have say "declaration"

Comment: @SJuan76, try reading STL headers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So if this is true, a program which includes more header
>   files would take more time to compile?

Of course. Strictly speaking, the more code the compiler needs to look at, the more time it needs to process it. For some really big projects, the amount of time needed to look at all the files easily becomes a concern. This is especially true for extraordinarily large and/or complex template code, which for practical reasons must reside in header files. The organization of the header files themselves also have an impact on compilation time.

*However*, it's not as simple as you think it is. It is highly dependent on the quality of implementation (QOI) of the compiler, and modern compilers nowadays are actually quite good at handling header files in most cases.

For example, [GCC specifically recognizes include guards](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Guard-Macros.html) to reduce processing time. And compilers nowadays are getting much better at handling complex template code e.g. most of the standard library. On VC++ compilers, including `windows.h` (which has function prototypes for almost the *entire* Windows API) does not appreciably increase compile times in my experience. And if all else fails, many if not all compilers have a "[precompiled headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header)" feature you can use.

Basically, don't worry about it until it becomes a problem. If having more header files helps to better organize your code, then by all means don't hesitate to use them.

Answer (score 6):

Generally yes, “a program which includes more header files would take more time to compile”.

---

Unfortunately, the preprocessed contents of a header can vary depending on which macro symbols are defined and how. And especially Microsoft's headers are generally *designed* to yield different results depending on such symbols (in standard C++ it's mainly just the `NDEBUG` symbol, which affects the expansion of `assert`). Therefore compilers are conservative and do the preprocessing and header compilation again and again *for each and every translation unit*.

One common technique to avoid that is so called **precompiled headers**.

One as far as I know uncommon technique, maybe not implemented by any compiler, is to allow the programmer to say that "for this batch of compilations you can assume that all headers will expand to the same", and maybe even have that as *default* (even if can yield different results from standard C++ when the assumption doesn't hold).

I would strongly prefer the latter approach, since it would speed up most any build, but precompiled headers is what we have in practice.

---

David Vandevoorde worked on a [**module** proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2316.pdf) for C++.

Examples of languages with modules: Modula-2, Ada, UCSD Pascal.

Unfortunately it was not ready for C++11, but maybe we'll get modules later.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically yes - the more code the longer compiler time. And everything you include, is places by pre-processor instead of include-statement as you already mentioned.

Practically it depends on what you include and how. If you include in a proper way, the impact on speed can be neglected. Including too much of standard headers creates rather name-space pollution then compile-time issues. The entire code of standard libraries is already compiled and will be only linked. 
In Qt you can either include each class separately (e.g. `#include <QWidget>`) or - a possibility for the lazy programmers - include all classes from a module (e.g. `#include <QtGui>`) which includes **thousands** of headers. So I never notices a considerable compile time difference between two methods.

Some thoughts and facts form my experience:

- *In silico* mentioned header guards. They are primarily not for compile-time optimization but for preventing circular inclusions. So
  if you include a header in 10 places, it will be parsed only once.
- In C++ include in headers only if you derive from a class in that
  header. Otherwise use forward declaration.
- Use private implementation idiom - so your headers will contain only
  one/couple of pointers.
- Don't include headers of your code, which you don't need in that
  c/cpp-file. A good build system analyses header dependences on the
  basis of include statements. Your code would be unnecessarily
  recompiled each time any of necessarily included headers had changed.
- Beside compilation time also linking time could be considerable. Make
  sure, the application consists of  DLLs (DLL/so files) So you could
  avoid linking all together on each compilation. In one project I've
  experienced linking time of about 10 minutes. The customer refused to
  use DLLs because of some esoteric reasons.
- If compiler time is really an issue it is worth looking under the
  hood of the build system. Some not trivial projects has to run
  post-/pre-build scripts. Check that the execution of those scripts
  only done if necessarily.
- In one project the complete-build time was reduced
  from 4hours to 40 minutes after making some modification to the make-tool.
  If you are on Linux check with strace how make works. You'll be
  astonished, how many unnecessary file accesses it makes.